# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException when use @Autowired

Tags: java, spring

**When i run the project I get a IllegalArgumentException,The problem is that I autowired the StudentService(it's a class implements IStudentService).But when I autowired the IStudentService,the problem is solved.People told me to do like this,but they don't tell me why.I want to know the reason which cause the problem.Any answers are appreciated :>**

> StudentController

```
@Controller
        public class StudentController {
            @Autowired
            StudentService studentService;

            @RequestMapping("get")
            public String get(){
                Student student = new Student();
                student.setName("abc");
                try {
                    studentService.save(student);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return "somwhere";
            }
        }
```

> StudentService

```
@Service
public class StudentService implements IStudentService{
    @Autowired
    IStudentDao studentDao;

    public Student getStudent(String id) throws Exception {
        return studentDao.query(id);
    }

    public List<Student> getAll() throws Exception{
        return studentDao.queryAll();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void save(Student student)throws Exception{
        studentDao.save(student);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void delete(Student student) throws Exception{
        studentDao.delete(student);
    }
}
```

> IStudentService

```
public interface IStudentService {
    public Student getStudent(String id) throws Exception;

    public List<Student> getAll() throws Exception;

    public void save(Student student)throws Exception;

    public void delete(Student student) throws Exception;
}
```

> stack trace

```
**Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'studentController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.gtis.service.StudentService com.gtis.controller.StudentController.studentService; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.gtis.service.StudentService field com.gtis.controller.StudentController.studentService to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:633)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:602)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:521)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:462)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:862)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1341)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1334)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:744)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyServer.doStart(JettyServer.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunWarExplodedMojo.execute(JettyRunWarExplodedMojo.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.gtis.service.StudentService com.gtis.controller.StudentController.studentService; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.gtis.service.StudentService field com.gtis.controller.StudentController.studentService to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
    ... 68 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.gtis.service.StudentService field com.gtis.controller.StudentController.studentService to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:741)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:513)
    ... 70 more

2016-03-30 11:34:58.126:WARN:/demo:main: unavailable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'studentController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.gtis.service.StudentService com.gtis.controller.StudentController.studentService; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.gtis.service.StudentService field com.gtis.controller.StudentController.studentService to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:633)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:602)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:521)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:462)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:862)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1341)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1334)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:744)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at *
```

Comment: Are you using any proxies like @Transaction ? or <tx:annotation-driven />

Comment: @Panther yes i did that,I use the Transaction annotation in the StudentService and <tx:annotation-driven /> in my application-context.xml

Comment: you need to show the stacktrace, it tells you exactly what line and what is wrong

Comment: @Jarrod Roberson I have post them

Comment: Spring is creating a proxy for your bean to handle transactions as your business method had a @Transactional annotation.As your StudentService class implements an interface Spring creates a JDK interface based proxy instead of a CGLIB class based proxy.This means that Spring creates a new class which implements IStudentService and delegates to your StudentService.The bean that Spring now manages and uses for injection is no longer a StudentService by inheritance but a proxy which is a IStudentService.If you really want to inject StudentService you can instruct Spring to proxy the class and not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in comments you are using Transaction annotation and `<tx:annotation-driven/>` tag is in your application context, it means your class in implementing the proxy interface, so spring is actually creating a object of new class which implements your interfaces but not inherit your class Student Service.
Therefore the autowiring is not working with Student  Service.

Comment: sorry i really want to do it,but it seems that i don't have enough reputation, sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

Spring is creating a proxy for your bean to handle transactions as your business method had a @Transactional annotation.As your StudentService class implements an interface Spring creates a JDK interface based proxy instead of a CGLIB class based proxy.This means that Spring creates a new class which implements IStudentService and delegates to your StudentService.The bean that Spring now manages and uses for injection is no longer a StudentService by inheritance but a proxy which is a IStudentService.If you really want to inject StudentService you can instruct Spring to proxy the class and not the interface using @EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass=true)

Comment: thank you very much! I tried to declaer the studentService as a bean in xml,and remove the Autowired in StudentController at the same time,i found the bean did injected,your answer explain why it's worked.The reason was the Spring proxy right?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, IStudentService is an interface. From the error you get, I'm guessing you have the IStudentService interface annotated as a Spring bean in your application context, but not the concrete class StudentService. So when Spring tries to find a bean to autowire, it doesn't see a bean of type StudentService.

Comment: I believe we cannot annotate the interface in application context, it needs concrete class.

Comment: Panther, I know that if you scan components in spring it can help find interfaces implemented by components, but I don't know why you wouldn't be able to use an interface for bean definition.

Comment: @Willcodeforfun i didn't , i just use the service annotation to claim it

Comment: @Willcodeforfun sorry my bad , i got confused and was thinking that we can use only class for concrete class. Ayways, in this case OP has used concrete class only.